# How to display <a> tag attribute “target” in the_author_meta( 'description' );

Tags: wordpress

This question is related to wordpress, anyone who is expert in wp php coding can help easily.

I am facing following problem:

Lets assume user has pasted his twitter id within "Biographical info" textarea using tag along with target _blank attribute, but the outcome for the_author_meta( 'description' ); discarded attribute target _blank of tag.

Any solutions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Seems no body has solution!

Well, I find out the solution by myself, I hope it will help some day somebody!

First of all you have to install wordpress plugin "Unlimited Contact Info" it will help you to add additional fields under user profile "contact info" after that add following code inside loop-single.php and author.php:

```
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('user_url')!='') { ?>
   <a href="<?php the_author_meta('user_url'); ?>" target="_blank">Website</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Note: For each field to show you have to repeat above code.

**The above mentioned solution is to show additional contact info / social network IDs (linked to their pages) for author of the post and link will be open in new window.**